# Count of records by grouping one column or another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in `mysql` like below.

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
|test1|  N|  2|null|
|test1|  N|  3|null|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I want `count` the values where either `tests` or `cnty` are having same values.

I have done like below

```
select tests, cnty, count(*) ask from db_name.table_name group by tests, cnty
```

The result I got is below

```
+-----+----+---+
|tests|cnty|ask|
+-----+----+---+
|test4|null|  1|
|test1|null|  3|
|test2|  UK|  1|
|test3| AUS|  1|
| null|  UK|  1|
+-----+----+---+
```

`expected result` is below

```
+-----+----+---+
|tests|cnty|ask|
+-----+----+---+
|test4|null|  1|
|test1|null|  3|
|test2|  UK|  2|
|test3| AUS|  1|
| null|  UK|  2|
+-----+----+---+
```

How can I achieve that?

> edit

`new table`

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
|test1|  N|  2|null|
|test1|  N|  3|null|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test1|  Y|  6|  US|
|test1|  Y|  6| IND|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

`expected result`

```
+-----+----+---+
|tests|cnty|ask|
+-----+----+---+
|test3| AUS|  1|
|test1|  US|  5|
|test2|  UK|  2|
|test4|null|  1|
| null|  UK|  2|
|test1|null|  5|
|test1| IND|  5|
+-----+----+---+
```

Comment: What should happen if the same `tests` value has different `cnty`?

Comment: @Barmar It should consider `tests` values first

Comment: Can you show sample input and output for that?

Comment: @Barmar updated question with new data and expected result

Comment: So `ask` should be the maximum of the `tests` and `cnty` counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ask` is the maximum of either the `tests` or `cnty` counts. So do one query that gets one count, another query that gets the other count, then join them with the main table and use the higher one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.tests, t.cnty, GREATEST(t1.count, t2.count) AS ask
FROM table_name AS t
JOIN (SELECT tests, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY tests) AS t1 ON t.tests <=> t1.tests
JOIN (SELECT cnty, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY cnty) AS t2 ON t.cnty <=> t2.cnty
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fe86/7)

It's necessary to use the `<=>` null-safe equality operator so that the null values in the table will be joined properly.